# Integral of a derivative.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, inverse

I've been learning the fundamental theorem of calculus.
So, I can intuitively grasp that the derivative of the integral of a given function brings you back to that function. 
Is this also the case with the integral of the derivative? And if so, can you please give a intuition for why this is true? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: (up to a constant term)

Comment: You need some assumptions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function for an example where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derivative and integral are *almost* inverse functions, so in turn, you are *almost* correct. For simple polynomials, one multiplies by the power and then removes 1 from the power, and the other adds 1 to the power and divide by the new power.

For more complex functions, you can consider it visually, or even compare it to physics. If you have a line (velocity), the gradient is the acceleration. If you derive this line to get the gradient, you know have the acceleration function. Now, if you have a flat line with no gradient (acceleration), and you integrate it, you will be left with a line with gradient for the velocity function.

This is because acceleration represents rate of change of distance relative to time, just like how gradient represents rate of change of y relative to x.

The only main difference is that integrating leaves you with an unknown constant $ C $. You may notice that if you differentiate $ f(x) = 2x^2 + 3x + 6 $, you're left with $ f'(x) = 4x + 3 $, and the $ 6 $ has absolutely no effect on the final answer. This is because, no matter where the line/curve is located in the y-axis, the gradient for the x co-ordinate remains the same. You require a co-ordinate from the *original* function in order to calculate $ C $.

Comment: In the final paragraph you write "if you integrate $f(x)=..." followed by "[then] you're left with f'(x)=...", did you mean to write "differentiate" instead?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 I did. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 9):

Since$$\int_a^xf'(t)\,\mathrm dt=f(x)-f(a),\tag{1}$$the short answer is that the integral of the derivative is the original function, up to a constant.

Of course, $(1)$ isn't true without restrictions. But if $f'$ is continuous, then, yes, $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Hi, Professor Santos. Could you please clarify why $f'$ needs to be continuous? Spivak's *Calculus* presents the 'Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus' as **not** requiring the assumption of continuity of the derivative.

Comment: @S.C. But it still requires that $f'$ is Riemann-integrable. On the other hand, I did **not** write that $f'$ *needs* to be continuous. All I wrote was that *if* $f'$ is continuous, then $(1)$ holds.

Comment: Isn't the Cantor function a counterexample? f'=0, which is continuous, Riemann-integrable, but it's integral is a constant, not the Cantor function.

Comment: @MSIS No, the Cantor function is not a counterexample, since it's not even a differentiable function.

Answer (score 2):

The integral of the derivative isn't always equal to the original function.

example : let $f$ be a function as $$f(x) = 2x+2$$
so we have $$f'(x)= 2$$

If you integrate $f'$, you'll end up with $$F(x) = 2x + c$$ with c a real constant. So you'll have your initial function only if $c=2$